# create image data in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I want to create a black (or white, I really don't care the "colour") 1x1px image in javascript, I tried doing it with `var img = new Image(1,1)` but I don't know how assigng the source of the image with `img.src` to be all black (I don't want to use a file, I want to be generated with JS code).

There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `base64 encoded` data in the `image.src`.

```js
var image = new Image(10, 10);
image.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNk+A8AAQUBAScY42YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

`var image = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d').getImageData(0,0,1,1);`

I'll let question open to know if there is another way to do it.

Sources I used:

- [CanvasRenderingContext2D.createImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createImageData)
- [CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly you can perform the image manipulation in canvas, then pass a data URI containing a representation of the image over to the HTML image for actual rendering.

```js
const imgWidth = 1;

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = imgWidth;
canvas.height = imgWidth;

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,imgWidth,imgWidth);

const url = canvas.toDataURL();
const newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.src = url;
document.body.insertBefore(newImg, null);
```